# facing issue ##[error]Error: Not found wrapperScript: /home/vsts/work/1/s/gradlew

Tags: javascript, react-native

2021-10-24T09:38:07.6018319Z ##[section]Starting: Build APK
2021-10-24T09:38:07.6029325Z ==============================================================================
2021-10-24T09:38:07.6029635Z Task         : Gradle
2021-10-24T09:38:07.6029893Z Description  : Build using a Gradle wrapper script
2021-10-24T09:38:07.6030167Z Version      : 3.192.0
2021-10-24T09:38:07.6030358Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-10-24T09:38:07.6030607Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle
2021-10-24T09:38:07.6030918Z ==============================================================================
2021-10-24T09:38:07.8239806Z ##[error]Error: Not found wrapperScript: /home/vsts/work/1/s/gradle/gradlew
2021-10-24T09:38:07.8306917Z ##[section]Finishing: Build APK

facing issue in the pipeline code
This is my pipeline code in Azure devops tool

```
# Node.js with React
# Build a Node.js project that uses React.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- pipeline

pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: 
   npm install
  displayName: 'Install node dependencies'

- script: 
   yarn install
  displayName: 'Install yarn'

- task: Gradle@3
  displayName: 'Build APK'
  inputs:
      workingDirectory: 'Android'
      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
      publishJUnitResults: false
      gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
      testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
      sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
      tasks: 'assembleRelease'

- task: AndroidSigning@3
  displayName: 'Sign APK'
  inputs:
      apkFiles: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/*.apk'
      apksignerKeystoreFile: 'my-upload-key.keystore'
      apksignerKeystorePassword: '$(AndroidKeyStorePassword)'
      apksignerKeystoreAlias: '$(AndroidKeyAlias)'
      apksignerKeyPassword: '$(AndroidKeyAliasPassword)'
      zipalign: true
  
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish APK to artifacts'
  inputs:
      PathtoPublish: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/release'
      ArtifactName: 'android'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Please help me resolve issue. The code is written in react-native language

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In my pipeline it shows "Not found wrapperScript: /home/vsts/work/1/s/gradlew" . I have setup and configure all the things but still not able to resolve issue that's  why the "build APK" failed again and again